# With Jekyll 3, can I transform a post's Markdown before actual Markdown parsing?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, responsive-images, kramdown

I would like to use the [Jekyll Responsive Image plugin](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image) to generate appropriate responsive images with `srcset`/`sizes` attributes for my posts' images.

But I would also like to be able to edit my posts in a software providing a live preview like [MacDown](http://macdown.uranusjr.com/), which only understands the standard Markdown syntax for images.

That's why I would like to know if there is a way —a plugin of some sort— to tell Jekyll to transform the standard Markdown syntax for images, which I would put in my Markdown files…

`![alt text](path/to/image.jpg)`

…into this syntax specific to the [Jekyll Responsive Image plugin](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image):

`{% responsive_image path: path/to/image.jpg alt: "alt text" %}`

And THEN, Jekyll could continue and use Kramdown to generate the HTML…

I also created [an issue in the plugin's Github](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image/issues/15), but a more general answer would be nice too, and maybe useful for other needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. Since Jekyll 3, you can have **multiple converters per file extension**. This allows you to create a converter like:

```
class ResponsiveImageify < Jekyll::Converter
  priority :high

  def matches(ext)
    ext.downcase == ".md"
  end

  def convert(content)
    content.gsub(/\!\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)/, '{% responsive_image path: \2 alt: \1  %}')
  end
end
```

That converter will `gsub` the content of any `.md` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried to use this in a new plugin, but it seems the Liquid syntax I generate with my [`Cloudinary` converter](https://github.com/nhoizey/nicolas-hoizey.com/blob/8f49a34dd444b000520aeb7731d0a8ca17415615/_plugins/cloudinary.rb#L84-L107) is not parsed after. Should I explicitly call Kramdown?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126629/how-is-the-priority-flag-in-jekyll-plugins-supposed-to-work

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to use new [Jekyll hooks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks)

A very raw plugin can be :

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :pre_render do |post, payload|
  docExt = post.extname.tr('.', '')
  # only process if we deal with a markdown file
  if payload['site']['markdown_ext'].include? docExt
    newContent = post.content.gsub(/\!\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)/, '{% responsive_image path: \2 alt: \1  %}')
    post.content = newContent
  end
end
```

Store this in `_plugins/img-tag-transform.rb`

Comment: I like [parkr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/716249/parkr)'s response better, but this one gives me new ideas too, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for this! FWIW, I amended the regex using named matched, also parsing out the `title` and having both `alt` and `title` being optional. So in my case, that one `gsub`-line looks like this: `new_content = post.content.gsub(/\!\[(?<alt>.+)?\]\((?<path>\S+) ?"?(?<title>.*?)"?\)/, '{% responsive_image path: \k<path> alt: "\k<alt>" title: "\k<title>" %}’)`.

Answer (score 0):

The examples posted here break the alt tag.
The alt string needs to be quoted otherwise it gets truncated into one word.

e.g. `content.gsub(/\!\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)/, '{% responsive_image path: \2 alt: "\1"  %}')`

Also Nicolas Hoizey's post is the only one that works for me on the latest version of Jekyll (3.7), I can't seem to make the other examples output html. Markdown appears to have been rendered before this inserts the liquid tags.