# How is the "priority" flag in Jekyll plugins supposed to work?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am currently trying to develop a plugin for Jekyll that would help use [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) for responsive images. Current source is [in my Github repo](https://github.com/nhoizey/nicolas-hoizey.com/blob/jekyll3/_plugins/cloudinary.rb), I will make it a gem later when/if it works.

This plugin has two features:

- a Liquid tag to define Cloudinary images like `{% cloudinary [preset] path/to/img.jpg [attr="value"] %}`
- a Converter to optionnaly automate transformation of standard Markdown/Kramdown syntax for images into this Liquid tag: `![alt text](path/to/img.jpg){:caption="caption text"}` becomes `{% cloudinary path/to/img.jpg alt="alt text" caption="caption text" %}`

Currently, both features work as intended, but they're not "chained". If I use the Liquid tag in my Markdown, it is evaluated. If I put a standard Markdown image, it is converted to the `{% cloudinary … %}` Liquid tag, but this tag is not evaluated.

I suspect the two features are not run in the right order, so I want to make sure the Converter is executed before the Liquid tag is evaluated.

But I didn't yet understand how to use the [priority flag](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#flags).

If I uncomment [the `priority :normal` line in my plugin](https://github.com/nhoizey/nicolas-hoizey.com/blob/8f49a34dd444b000520aeb7731d0a8ca17415615/_plugins/cloudinary.rb#L26), and run `bundle exec jekyll serve`, I get this error:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/nhoizey/Dropbox/Personnel/Devs/nicolas-hoizey.com/_config.yml
jekyll 3.1.6 | Error:  undefined method `priority' for Jekyll::CloudinaryTag:Class
Did you mean?  print
```

Any idea?

**EDIT (July 11th):**

I have now split it into to plugins.

The Converter is still in my site's `_plugins` folder: https://github.com/nhoizey/nicolas-hoizey.com/blob/52c92a38410e133890eea6044a033cb20344b971/_plugins/cloudinaryfy.rb#L26

Jekyll doesn't complain with this "priority" flag.

The Liquid tag is now a true autonomous plugin gem named `jekyll-cloudinary`: https://nhoizey.github.io/jekyll-cloudinary/

If I put the "priority" flag in this plugin, I still get the error:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve                                                                                 bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/usr/local/bin/jekyll)
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'jekyll-cloudinary'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `priority' for Jekyll::Cloudinary::CloudinaryTag:Class
Did you mean?  print
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-cloudinary-1.2.2/lib/jekyll/cloudinary.rb:5:in `<class:CloudinaryTag>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-cloudinary-1.2.2/lib/jekyll/cloudinary.rb:4:in `<module:Cloudinary>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-cloudinary-1.2.2/lib/jekyll/cloudinary.rb:2:in `<module:Jekyll>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-cloudinary-1.2.2/lib/jekyll/cloudinary.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-cloudinary-1.2.2/lib/jekyll-cloudinary.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-cloudinary-1.2.2/lib/jekyll-cloudinary.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.1.6/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:34:in `require_from_bundler'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.1.6/bin/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:

  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:89:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.1.6/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:34:in `require_from_bundler'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.1.6/bin/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<top (required)>'
```

Why is it working for one plugin but not the other?

How can I make sure the `cloudinarify` Converter plugin runs before the `jekyll-cloudinary` Liquid tag is interpreted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `priority` flag was introduced for subclasses of `Jekyll::Plugin` in order to give plugin authors the ability to explicitly give ordering information to Jekyll. Plugin subsclasses are instantiated and sorted by priority when a new `Jekyll::Site` is instantiated. If you want your `cloudfoundry` plugin to be run *before* or *after* another plugin, you modify its priority so it will come before the other plugin in terms of processing.

This is only valid for subclasses of `Jekyll::Plugin`, which includes `Jekyll::Converter` and `Jekyll::Generator`. This is why it works for your converter, but not for your `Liquid::Tag` – liquid tags do not have the idea of a priority because they do not compete.

For example, take the case of a site which has a **category generator plugin** and a **sitemap plugin**. The sitemap plugin author wants to ensure that any generated pages are present in the sitemap (all content should be in the sitemap!), so it sets `priority :low`. The category generator plugin author may want to ensure it runs before any other generator, such as a sitemap generator, so it sets `priority :high`. This ensures the category generator plugin is run before the sitemap plugin such that the compiled sitemap has the category pages in it.

The default priority is `:normal`. In descending order of precedence, there is:

- `:highest`
- `:high`
- `:normal`
- `:low`
- `:lowest`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Now that I know that my `Liquid::Tag` "do not compete", is there a way to make it work **after** my `Jekyll:Converter`? If I try to explain the sequence I need: normal Markdown image syntax -(`Jekyll::Converter`)-> Liquid tag syntax -(`Liquid::Tag`)-> HTML. I don't know if they are currently run in the other order, or even in parallel… do I have to call the Kramdown converter myself at the end of my own Converter? I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169849/how-to-get-markdown-processed-content-in-jekyll-tag-plugin/35799486#35799486

Comment: @NicolasHoizey Liquid always runs first, so your tag should be run before the document is converted **unless** you put the tag in the layout. The process is in `Jekyll::Rendered#run`: [liquid on the doc](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/4b5126dda7f1e00d2701404b4f1ec2d155f40857/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb#L62), [convert doc](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/4b5126dda7f1e00d2701404b4f1ec2d155f40857/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb#L66), then [run doc through its layouts with liquid only](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/4b5126dda7f1e00d2701404b4f1ec2d155f40857/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb#L71).

Comment: ok, so I'll try to call my Liquid tag interpreter directly in my Converter, thanks again for the answers. I think these could enhance the Jekyll documentation.

Comment: Oh well, I just discovered this old issue… :-/ https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/889

Comment: Not quite true that plugins don't compete. If you're writing a plugin designed to *extend* another plugin, you need to ensure it loads after it!